# Cannot store data correctly in memory on ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I'm learning ARM assembly, using Keil uVision IDE to simulate on intel-windows system.

I'm trying to store a data in a register to the memory with using `STR R5, [R12]`.
the values are generated before, and stored correctly until the value in R5 hits 377. (The value before 377 is 233.) I assume this is a problem caused by the size of the value in binary.

Since 233 = 1110 1001 and 377 =  0001 0111 1001. value is passing over the 8-bits.

Here is the part of the code that I think is problematic:

```
LDR R6, [R3],#1 ; loads data from memory to R6
LDR R7, [R4],#1 ; loads data from memory to R7

ADD R5, R6, R7  ; adds them (in this case its 144+233=377)
STR R5, [R12],#1; stores the value '377' to the memory.
```

The value in the memory pane looks like this:
[image: The memory of the program]

instead of 377, its 121.

I've added a breakpoint and observed the value of R5 in debug mode, its correctly holding 377 in R5. So; the problem is to write that 377.

Any ideas why this happens and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You realize that LDR does 32-bit/4-byte loads and STR also does 32-bit/4-byte stores?

Comment: @ErikEidt Yes I know that, and I'm surprised why the program behaves like this.

Answer (score 3):

377<sub>10</sub> doesn't fit in 8 bits.  Truncated to 8 bits, as if subtracting 256, the value becomes 0111 1001, which is 121<sub>10</sub>.

Since you're using loads and stores of 4 byte entities, but working with bytes, I believe that you're getting more data in the registers than you expect.  Hence the values past 121, namely, 098 & 219...

---

All modern hardware is what we call [byte addressable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing).

On a byte addressable machine, each byte has its own address.  So, when you store a 4 byte integer, it takes 4 bytes, and since it takes 4 bytes, it also takes 4 addresses!

If you choose to, you can look at the individual bytes, but that's not the big picture.  Taken alone and individually, each byte of the 4 doesn't represent the 4 byte value, but all together the 4 bytes do.

When you store a 4 byte integer, you must allow it 4 byte addresses.  So, if one 4-byte integer is located at 0x20000400, then the next available address for storing anything else is 0x20000404, because 0x20000400-0x20000403 are in use storing that 4 byte integer.

If you choose to store a 4 byte integer at location 0x20000401, that will overwrite the memory used by the former 4 byte integer stored at 0x20000400.

Suggest you avoid all complex addressing modes so you can see in the register the exact effective address.

So, instead of doing `LDR R6, [R3],#1`, if you really want to use offset of +1, then do `ADD R6,R3,#1` followed by `LDR R6,[R6]`.  This will simplify your debugging.

But you probably shouldn't be using an offset of +1 anyway, since we now understand that 4-byte integers take 4 addresses.  Offsets of +0 and +4 make sense here, not +1.

Comment: Any idea about how to get around this problem?

Comment: What problem are you trying to work around?  If you want to store the number 377, that will take more bytes than one, no getting around that.  Suggest you work with 4-byte integers instead of 1-byte integers.

Comment: I need to store 377, in one piece, in the memory. Tried to use LDRD instead of LDR but did not worked (Assumed trying to store Double Word could help me)

Comment: You can store 377 in two bytes or in 4 bytes, but those are about the limit of the options. Suggest you work with 4-byte integers.  It's what we do when we need numbers bigger than 256.  Can you explain why you don't want to try or why 4-byte integers won't work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to the Arm asm, I actually don't know how to "use" and "not use" 1 byte int and 4 byte integers. I know that LDR and STR are using 4 bytes, and still trying to understand why the program tries to fit 377 into 8 bits and faces a truncation. Could you please provide simpler explanation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried.  You really need to understand memory, and this not an assembly-specific concept.  You can play with memory, addresses and indexing in C:  `int a[100]; printf ("%p %p %p\n", a, &a[1], &a[2]);`  Once you understand memory and addressing, you will see that in assembly index scaling is explicit whereas in C index scaling is implicit.